# existence of normal family of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces

A set $F ⊂ A(Ω)$ is normal iff every sequence in $F$ contains a subsequence
converging uniformly on compact subsets of $Ω$. ($A(\Omega)$ means the set of all analytic function in $\Omega$).

> Show that there exists $\left\{f_n:n∈N \right\} ⊂ A(D)$, where $D=\left\{z:|z|<1\right\}$,  such that each $f_n$ maps $D$ conformally onto $D$ and $f_n → 1$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$.

How to prove existence of such family? any help please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_n(z)=\frac{z+a_n}{1+\bar a_n z}$ for any $|a_n|<1, a_n \to 1$ will do; take for example $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$ ($f_n(0)=a_n \to 1$ so any normal covergent subsequence of $f_n$ must converge to $1$ by maximum modulus, but the family is uniformly bounded so it must converge normally to $1$ as any subsequence has a convergent sub-subsequence)

Comment: Thank you for helping...I was confused how to prove the existence.

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: Conrad, do you have time to help me on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637024/determine-where-does-a-set-of-functions-contain-a-normal-family....