# Determine where does a set of functions contain a normal family

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

For what regions $\Omega$ is the family of functions $F_{\Omega}=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{f:f(z)=sin(nz),z \in \Omega\}$ normal?

A family $F$ is said to be normal in $n$ if every sequence $\{f_{n}\}$
 of functions in $F$ contains a subsequence which converges uniformly on every compact subset of $n$.

I have problems dealing with normal families ...

Any help, please.

Comment: is compact divergence to infinity allowed in your definition of normal or not (that corresponds to compact convergence to $\infty$ in the extended plane so some definition of normal families allow it, some not); if not you have to bound the imaginary part for sure

Comment: compact divergence to ifinity not allowed.

Comment: If $\Im z =y \ne 0$, $2|\sin nz|=|\alpha e^{-ny}-\beta e^{ny}| \ge e^{n|y|}-e^{-n|y|} \to \infty$ with $n$ where$ |\alpha|=|\beta|=1$ by the triangle inequality and the definition of $\sin$ so the family is not locally bounded on any compact set that has non real elements and since regions must have such points, the family cannot be normal on any region

Comment: what will happen if the compact convergence to infinity  is allowed..??

Comment: I'm sorry for all these questions...but I try to understand...I don't know any thing about normal families except this def "A set $F ⊂ A(Ω)$ is normal iff every sequence in $F$ contains a subsequence
converging uniformly on compact subsets of $Ω$" ...

Comment: If compact divergence to infinity is allowed, then any domain (open set enough) that doesn't intersect the real axis works since as noted $|\sin nz| \to \infty$ with $n$ then for fixed $z$ and if $|y| \ge c >0$ , $y=\Im z, z \in F$ which happens if we are in a compact $F$ avoiding $\mathbb R$, then for every $M>0$ there is $N(M, F), |\sin nz| >M, n>N(M,F), z \in F$ which is the defintion of compact divergence

Comment: for usual normal families (no compact divergence to infinity) Montel's theorem gives family normal if and only if family is locally uniformly bounded

Comment: Thank you for clarification.